# CSS - Having to set width of DIV with overflow hidden

Tags: css

I have some floated divs in a wrapper, they should be side buy side and a fixed width. However as together the child divs are wider than the parent div this has been set to overflow:hidden;

My problem is I have to set the width of the parent div to accommodate the combined width of the child divs otherwise they are pushed onto a new line by the lack of available width.

I would like to not have to set the width of the wrapper div if possible as the child divs will be added dynamically.

**Css:**

```
.shell{
    width:900px;
}

.wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:120px;
    margin-top:35px;
    width:1000px; 
}

.cont{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    position: relative; 
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="shell">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="cont">
      </div>
      <div class="cont">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The `relative:position;` must be kept for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap{
overflow:hidden;
height:120px;
margin-top:35px;
min-width:1000px;
width:auto; 
}
```

if you want to view them side by side , then you should consider using `inline-block`

that is why we use min-width , just to initiate a width

Comment: Even with min-wdith and inline-block I am having to specify a min-widht that is larger than the total width of the children.

Comment: then why not just set it to auto ?!

Comment: @user1209203 please clarify the problem i dont get it